# Image gallery in rails with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image-gallery

I am trying to make a very simple website for myself - I will have a lot of albums with photos of home interiors. I want to implement image gallery for every album. Thing that I can not solve is getting the right image when I click on it. When I do console.log I can see that correct image is selected but it never comes to view. Maybe someone can help me here?
This is my code:

```
 Album show page:



<h4 class="text-center" id= "album-title">
 <%= @album.title %>
</h4>
<div class="text-center album-body">
 <%= @album.body %>
</div>


<!-- app/views/posts/show.html.erb -->
 <% if @album.images.attached? %>
<div class="card-columns">
    <% @album.images.each do |image| %>
        <%= image_tag image.variant(resize: "250x250"), class: "card album-image gallery-item" %>
        <%= link_to "Remove", delete_image_attachment_album_url(image), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} if current_admin %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</div>  

<div class = "lightbox">
 <div class = "lightbox-content">
    <div class = "lightbox-controls">
        <a href="#" class="lightbox-close">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="lightbox-prev"> < </a>
        <a href="#" class="lightbox-next"> > </a>
    </div>
 <div class = "lightbox-image"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

And this is my jquery code that I wrote so far..

```
 $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $(".lightbox").hide();
});

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
$(".lightbox-close").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
$(".lightbox").hide();
 });
});

for(i = 0; i < $(".gallery-item").length; i++) { 
let item = $(".gallery-item")[i];
item.onclick = function(event) {
$(".lightbox").show();
let elementClickedOn = event.target;
console.log(elementClickedOn)
 }
}
```

What do I need to write to get this elementClickedOn to appear in a lightbox?

Comment: The workflow would be, Onclick handler on the <IMG> tag, which does two things: add another <img> tag to the lightbox with the full image, unhide the lightbox. Don't forget to reset the lightbox when closing it, by clearing/removng the <img> tag.

Comment: Where should I put this onclick handler? In my show page?

Comment: On each <img> tag